# Worklight / iOS7 Screen Shifted above While navigation

Tags: ios, dojo, ios7, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have developed one application using IBM Worklight and deployed it on iOS7 device. I have noticed that while navigation screen shifted above and status bar comes over the screen for 1 second and then the screen comes down to its natural position. This happens while we navigate from one screen to another screen. Any body has any idea how to disable this movement. This was not happening in iOS 6 device.

[image]

I have used Dojo and my Worklight version is 6.0.0.1

regards,
V@run

Comment: Please edit the question and further explain the "navigating from one screen to another" - example?

Comment: Is this implemented natively? Dojo? jQuery Mobile? No 3rd party framework? Still need more information. Also add your exact Worklight version. All information you have - add it to the question.

Comment: Hi Idan, After navigation, status bar showing the network connection and time comes down on navigation bar of the screen for 1 second and then adjusted correctly as shown above.

Comment: Yes Idan, I have used Dojo Mobile framework.

Comment: Worklight version: 6.0.0.1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40236/discussion-between-varun-mehta-and-idan-adar)

Comment: read in details this article (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039574), especially the part about the status bar. You may have to disable this feature and make your own design.

Comment: also: https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17527  or other DoJo articles

Comment: Hi Nathan, That document helped..i did showIOS7StatusBar : false  in initOptions.js file and then hide the status bar.

Comment: Varun, is your problem solved ? (not clear from your last comments)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by Nathan Hazout in the [TechNote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039574), Worklight will try to allow 20px at the top of the screen to accommodate the iOS7 status bar.

This is accomplished by:

1. Adding CSS class "wl_ios7" to the "body" element
2. Adding a "div" element with id "wl_ios7bar" with 20px height before the web view content

(You can check that by looking at the Worklight app DOM elements with the Web Inspector)

This solution will not always work and in your case it seems that it works only partially.

When "showIOS7StatusBar" is set to false, Worklight will not attempt to handle the iOS7 status bar, leaving this task entirely to you. It is worth noting that on iOS6 and below the status bar is handled automatically by the OS.

There is not enough information on your question so I can only help with generic suggestions. What has been working well for me is to use CSS [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to add "padding-top: 20px" to the "body" element as such:

```
@media (min-height: 568px) and (orientation: portrait), (min-height: 320px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    #content {
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
}
```

That works because on iOS7 the iPhone height is 568px while for iOS6 and below it is 548px ("document.documentElement.clientHeight"). For landscape the values are 320px and 300px respectively. I also like this solution because it is a bit more in line with the [RWD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) approach.

With variations of this suggestion I have been able to handle the status bar relatively well on my small projects, but keep in mind that your milage may vary.